# How to check if an OLE object has been printed in the Crystal Report?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, report

I have placed a picture (OLE object) in the group footer and I need to check whether this object is printed in the current worksheet or not. So basically I want to detect the end of group and update an object (string) which is placed in the group header. Is this possible in the formula editor?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using regular formula logic.

But if you know the group header always starts at the top of the page, you could try to compute the vertical space required by the following sections (by knowing their heights and number) and use that information to figure out if the page has enough remaining space for the group footer.

Comment: Ohh no. The content in the report is dynamic so cannot use remaining space as identifier for end of each group.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the content of the report is dynamic but you can compute the required space by knowing how many items are in the group.  For example, if the only section under the Group Header is the detail section, and the height of the detail section is X, and the number of records in the group is 10, then the vertical space is 10X.